# iPhone app with iAds recieving error code 3 when run on iPad with iOS 5.0

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, iad

I have an iPhone app that is currently using the test environment for iAds. The ads display when `bannerViewDidLoadAd:` is received and hides the ads when `didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` is received, which is what I would expect.

After loading the app on an iPad 2 running iOS 5.0 I noticed no ads were showing. I ran the same app in the 5.0 simulator, which produced the same results: no iAds. After setting a few breakpoints I noticed that the app only receives `didFailToReceiveAdWithError:`, once, at the first launch of the app, but running the iPad 4.3 simulator worked as expected. The ads also display properly on a physical iPad running 4.2.1.

Has anyone else had this issue with an iPhone app with iAds not displaying ads on an iPad running iOS 5 and above?

xcode: 4.2
sdk: 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem others are having this issue as well. The [MyStream app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mystream/id423918810?mt=8) (v 1.4.1) iPhone only app is having the same issue. Running the app on my:

- iphone (iOS 5.0) I see iAds
- iPad 2 (iOS 4.x) I see iAds
- iPad (iOS 5.0) NO iAds

Looks like it might be something it iAds itself.